# Какой атрибут потока подобрать чтобы вывелась ошибка при вызове pthead_create

Tags: ос, posix

Мне дали задание по ОС. Мне нужно подобрать такой атрибут потока, при котором функция pthread_create() вернет ошибку, и вывести текст этой ошибки, сформированный системной функцией ОС, на экран.